# How to apply an icon to your file in visual studio? {Console C++ Application}

Tags: c++, visual-studio, console

I have tried to apply an icon to my exe, but I don't know how to?

I am new to stack overflow and this is my first question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Open the project and add .rc file
[image]

[image]

2.`Right click Resource.rc->Add Resource->Icon->Improt` in `Recourse View`. Then, import the `icon` that you want. The picture must be `.ico` format.

[image]

3. Then, you could find that the `icon` has been added.

Besides, if you have many pictures, you could open `resource.h` and change the value of the `icon` to minimum. Because the program chooses the smallest id number as the icon. For example, change the value of `IDC_ICON1` from 129 to 103.

[image]

Comment: Ohk tysm :D sorry for late reply :(